# Not sure why limit converges to given value?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to figure out what

$ \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} e(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$

converges to

What I did was using L'Hospital's Rule I proved

$ \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{a}{n})^n = e^{a}$

Next I factored out the "e" since it isn't dependent on n.

$ e(\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{n})^n)$

Using the formula the inner limit should be equal to $e^{-1}$.

$ e(\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{n})^n)= e(e^{-1})=1$

The problem I'm having is when I plug in large numbers instead of the limit converging to 1 it seems to converge to something else.

$ \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} e(1-\frac{1}{n})^n = 1-\frac{1}{2n}$

I'm wondering what is it that I'm doing wrong and what strategy do you use to get the right answer?

This problem that I'm trying to solve is part of another limit I'm trying to evaluate. The limit is

$ \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} ne(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$

If the limit of

$ e(\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{n})^n)=1$

Then

$ \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} ne(1-\frac{1}{n})^n = n$

but it ends up being

$ \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} ne(1-\frac{1}{n})^n = n -\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I think that you may have some typos in your question, because all of your limits are as $x\to\infty$, but you don't have any $x$'s anywhere :)

Comment: I suspect you mean $\lim_{n\to \infty}$. In that case, how does the limit value depend on $n$?

Comment: sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

The sign $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ binds the integer variable $n$ to the inside of the limit. It is misleading to write terms in $n$ on the right side outside of the limit.

Using $e=(e^{1/n})^n$ one can get your results in a still rather elementary way as
\begin{align}
e(1-\tfrac1n)^n
&=\left(1+\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}+O(n^{-3})\right)^n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n
\\
&=\left(1-\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{2n^2}+O(n^{-3})\right)^n
\\
&=\left(1-\frac1{2n^2}+O(n^{-3})\right)^n
\\
&=1-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})
\end{align}
Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}e(1-\tfrac1n)^n=1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\Bigl(e(1-\tfrac1n)^n-1\Bigr)=-\frac12$.

---

The not so elementary way is to see
$$
\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n=\exp(n·\ln(1-\tfrac1n))=\exp(n(-\tfrac1n-\tfrac1{2n^2}-\tfrac1{3n^3}-\tfrac1{4n^4}-…))\\
=\exp(-1-\frac1{2n}-\frac1{3n^2}-…)=e^{-1}(1-\frac1{2n}- \frac5{24n^2} - \frac5{48n^3} + O(n^{-4}))
$$

Comment: I'm not sure what O(n^(-3)) or O(n^(-2)) stands for do you mind explaining that?

Comment: This is the Landau notation and means that the remainder  is a bounded multiple of $n^{-3}$ or $n^{-2}$. The use of the exponential series for $e^{1/n}$ is ok?

Answer (score 1):

May be another way (very similar to LutzL's answer) considering $$A=e\,(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$$ $$\log(A)=\log(e)+n\log(1-\frac{1}{n})=1+n\log(1-\frac{1}{n})$$ Now, using for small $x$, Taylor expansion $\log(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$; replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{n}$ and get $$\log(A)=1+n(-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\cdots)=-\frac{1}{2n}+\cdots$$ So $$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\log(A)=0 \quad\,\quad \lim_\limits{n\to \infty}A=1 $$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.
And by plugging big numbers in, you seem to get $\lim_{n \to \infty} e(1-\frac{1}{n})^n = 1 - \frac{1}{2n}$. However, the RHS is still depending on $n$, so you also need a limit of $n \to \infty$ there, so the correct equation for the large numbers would be $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} e(1-\frac{1}{n})^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 - \frac{1}{2n} = 1 -\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n} = 1$$
which correspond with your limit gotten by L'Hospital.

Comment: The 1-1/2n affects the second part of the question. Instead of the limit being n it ends up being n-1/2. I would like to know why the limit converges to 1-1/2n instead of 1.